# Remove Firefox's Web Console

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Firefox's built-in web console is conflicting with Firebug and stealing the JavaScript logs.
How can I disable/remove this built-in web console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Firefox Support Forum](https://support.mozilla.org/pt-PT/questions/962490)

> You can search for devtools.*.enabled via the Search bar at the top of the about:config page.

I think `devtools.errorconsole.enabled` is what you want.

Comment: Can't find devtools.errorconsole.enabled in FF 51 :-(